# Error when trying to connect the MySQL database to my Python application

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create my database connection, but it gives an error and I can't identify where it is.
I attach some code snippets to facilitate understanding.

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K73Jq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqmhx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cCw1.png)

The first lines of the connect_bd function run correctly, but I don't understand how it could have given an error on three different lines.